# How to add multiple shapefiles with C# ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have a folder contain 5 shapefiles.

I want to develop C# code for adding the 5 shapefiles with single button click.

I have created code for adding a single shapefile but how can I add multiple shapefiles?

```c#
ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument mxd = ArcMap.Application.Document as ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap map = mxd.FocusMap;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory wsf = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace ws = wsf.OpenFromFile(@"D:\ARC OBJECTS\Kothagudem Attribute Data", ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace fws = ws as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass fcls = fws.OpenFeatureClass("Agriculture.shp");
ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer lay = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayerClass();
lay.FeatureClass = fcls;
lay.Name = fcls.AliasName;
map.AddLayer(lay);
```

Comment: What have you tried? In what way did it fail? It seems like you want us to teach looping in C#, but that isn't a GIS task.

Comment: Have a look at [IGPUtilities.OpenFeatureLayerFromString](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGPUtilities_OpenFeatureLayerFromString.htm) stops you having to write so much code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over feature classes in an IWorkspace by using

```
IEnumDataset eds = ws.Datasets[esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass]
```

You can then write a function like this to access those feature classes easily

```
IEnumerable<IFeatureClass> getFeatureClasses(IEnumDataset eds)
{
    IDataset ds;
    while ((ds = eds.Next()) != null)
        yield return ds as IFeatureClass;
}
```